# JSTL Scriptlet to java class

Tags: java, performance, jstl, el

I'm pretty new to Java so bear with me. I have a scriptlet that
is put into a JSTL tag. I'm trying to do away with my scriptlets 
and put them in a seperate class. Except I'm really stumped on this
one.  I have a pretty basic Java method:

```
static final String default = "Enter a message";

String subDate(String out){
    final String year = "" + Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
    return out.replaceAll("%CURRYEAR%", year);
}
```

In my JSTL I call it like below

```
<c:out value="<%= subDate(msg) %>" default="<%= subDate(default) %>"
```

When I'm converting this to my Java class this is what I have. But I'm 
simply not getting anything. I'm also really confused on how I would
pass it multiple parameters like I'm doing in my JSTL.

```
public String getsubDate(String in){        
    return in.replaceAll("%CURRYEAR%", YEAR) + getMsg();            
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm assuming your JSTL tag is `c:out` and `msg` contains the string `%CURRYEAR%`? How are you getting `msg` to the page, something like `request.setAttribute('msg', '%CURRYEAR%')` in a servlet?

Comment: @clav sorry I should have been more specific. My jstl is c:out and yes msg is being output to the page via request.setAttribute.

Comment: The problem is not about JSTL but expression language (most known as EL). Please give a look at [StackOverflow EL wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info), specially the Introduction and EL functions sections.

Answer (score 0):

Since it sounds like you're putting `msg` on the request in the servlet using `request.setAttribute`, you can get the correct year in the servlet, replace all occurances of  `%CURRYEAR%` right there and just put the correct message on the request:

```
String year = "" + Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
request.setAttribute("msg", msg.replaceAll("%CURRYEAR%", year));
```

Then on your page just do this:

```
<c:out value="${msg}" />
```

Comment: The problem is about how to apply a function on EL variables.

Comment: I know he's trying to use an EL function to put provide the current year to `c:out` tag, but my point is there's really no need for an EL function here at all. Look at his comment, he's just putting the `%CURRYEAR%` placeholder on the request with `request.setAttribute`. It's far simpler to just get the correct date and put it on the request and provide it to `c:out` with and EL expression.

Comment: while you could be right in your comment, that's not what your answer reflects.

Comment: My answer does exactly what my comment says, it puts the current year on the request using `request.setAttribute` and then accesses it using an EL expression in a `c:out` tag.

Comment: Your answer doesn't use the `replaceAll` as stated in question (twice). Based on this, your answer doesn't cover what OP needs.

Comment: That's my whole point, he doesn't need to do `replaceAll`. Look at my first comment and his answer to it. What he was doing was putting `%CURRYEAR%` on the request in a servlet like this `request.setAttribute('msg', '%CURRYEAR%')`. He wanted to make an EL function to replace his scriplets that replaced `%CURRYEAR%` with the current year. Why put `%CURRYEAR%` on the request and make an EL funtion to replace it when you can just put the correct year on request in the first place?

Comment: AFAICS, there's a big `String` (called `in` or `out`, depending on the method) which contains inner template fields in form of substrings as *%CURRYEAR%* that must be replaced by something at runtime. Again, your answer is failing to accomplish this. Also, note that this big `String` can (I can bet it) contains several of these template fields.

Comment: My mistake, I accidentally forgot to put the replaceAll call in the servlet code example and didn't notice that at first.   I don't think he needs an EL function to replace the %CURRYEAR% placeholders since it sounds like he has `msg` in the servlet and is just putting it on the request.